# How to enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties` in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a REST api for my application in Nodejs and Express. But each time i try to send a request I get an undefined error. Please how can i enable 'ignoreundefinedproperties'

Answer (score 105, accepted):

once you import the firebase-admin sdk (in Typescript) like this

```
import * as firestore from "firebase-admin";
```

then you just need to set the setting like this :

```
const db = firestore.firestore();
db.settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true })
```

Comment: Error : Error: Firestore has already been initialized. You can only call settings() once, and only before calling any other methods on a Firestore object.

Comment: @Navneet is there a way to use this setting once?

Answer (score 31):

If you are getting errors for calling this more than once, I recommend putting `admin.firestore().settings({ignoreUndefinedProperties:true});` in the same place you have `admin.initializeApp();`

Here's how I did it in my Typescript project

initialize.ts:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import 'firebase-functions';


admin.initializeApp();
admin.firestore().settings({ignoreUndefinedProperties:true});
```

Top of index.ts:

```
import './initialize.ts'
```

Answer (score 17):

For anyone using the v9 API:

```
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator, initializeFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'; // Firebase v9+

// Must be called before getFirestore()
initializeFirestore(app, {
  ignoreUndefinedProperties: true
});
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
```

Comment: what about firebase-admin?

Comment: @ChukwuemekaMaduekwe then just use the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore';

initializeApp();
const db = getFirestore();
db.settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true });
```

Inspired by other answers present here, but this one shows `firebase-admin` way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing error (*Firestore has already been initialized. You can only call settings() once*) even after trying other answers, restart your IDE/VSCode and terminal. This is what worked for me.

Comment: Similarly unknown cause of frustration...  tsc --watch mode on typescript compiler was missing some change that made this firestore error persist for me. Solution was a full build: tsc

Answer (score 0):

Im using `firebase-admin@^11.5.0`:

```js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import serviceAccount from "./firebase-admin-sdk.json";

const app = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount as admin.ServiceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://{database-id}.firebaseio.com/",
});

const firestore = app.firestore();
firestore.settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true });
export firestore;
```

So when i import firestore, the `ignoreUndefinedProperties` will set true once.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.